# Playing non-pcm (gsm) ".wav"-file in Internet Explorer 8 and 9

Tags: c#, asp.net, audio, wav, gsm

Good day. Help me in my problem. please.

I need to play ".wav"-file (GSM 6.10, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, 0 bits per sample, Block Align: 65, Average Bytes Per Second: 1625) in Internet Explorer 8 and 9.

IE9 played this file in [embed] WMP, but IE8 isn't. I tried to convert it in the mp3 or wma (only for IE8), but it not work.

Help me please and excuse me for my english.

Answer (score 2):

Multimedia is not an easy thing to get right with web browsers. Firstly, all browsers implement things slightly differently. Supporting IE can be a nightmare because Microsoft tend to update certain things from one version of IE to another, meaning you can end up building sites with masses of messy code to support IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9 (IE10...) as well as FireFox, Chrome, Safari etc.

It is better to support web standards, not browsers! Therefore...

1. If applicable you should use the new HTML5 *audio* element (mp3 / ogg)
2. Use a fallback media player supporting your format. (you already mentioned you are using WMP embedded, but there are flash/silverlight ones available for free too.) You use the fallback where the audio element is not supported.
3. additional: consider using Modernizr to check what standards/features a browser supports:
   http://www.modernizr.com/

Research the HTML 5 audio tag here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp

Research playing audio in HTML here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Layton, thank you for your answer. 
HTML 5 is not my because IE 9 don't suppurt "GSM-wav" in `<audio>` tag. I find this solution and it works for me:

```
                    <object id="Player_O" classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
                        codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="70px" 
                        type="application/x-oleobject" width="400px">
                        <param name="url" value="C:\1.wav">
                        <param name="autostart" value="false">
                        <embed id="Player_E" height="70px" 
                            pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" 
                            src="file:///C:/1.wav" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="400px"></embed>
                        </param>
                        </param>
                    </object>
```